# Samsung Galaxy S5; Changing ISO-speed settings with camera API

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, iso, s5

I'm trying to set the ISO for the Samsung Galaxy S5 using the Camera API. 
The parameters which includes the ISO tag in the Camera Parameters (retreived using camera.getParameters.flatten();) are:

- exif_iso=0;
- iso=auto;
- iso-values=auto,ISO_HJR,100,200,400,800,1600;

I quess that the exif_iso parameter has something to do with the Meta file, so i don't need that. The iso setting is what i need, and i can choose all the values stated under iso-values. If i set one of these parameters, the parameters are accepted (no exception is getting thrown). If i use a parameters which isn't stated under the values, an exception is thrown. So the value of iso are set!

But... the strange thing is that when you take a picture, the iso setting seems to be ignored. Settings like white balance and resolution work like a charm, but i can't get the iso to change. On another phone (galaxy S2) the iso setting does work.

In the official camera app from samsung, the iso value is editable, so somewhere in the api it should be possible! I have tried some camera apps from the play store (including open camera 1.20) but the same thing; you can change the value but it gets ignored.

Has anyone any idea why the value is ignored? is there maybe another parameter which enables or disables this kind of settings?

Thanks a lot :)

***Update:***
I'am a little bit further. It seems to be caused by OpenCV which i also use in my app. Specifically the class CameraBridgeViewBase seems to cause the iso setting problem. Even i disable the view before taking the picture, the iso settings are getting ignored. I've build a little camera app without the use of OpenCV and the iso is set just like it should.

If an app with CameraBridgeViewBase been running (even if you clear the memory after that) my camera test app iso settings are ignored again. I also tried the app 'open camera', the iso settings are simply ignored again. If i start the official samsung camera app, it seems like it resets the whole camera; My camera test app and 'open camera' iso setting work again after that.

The weird thing of all is that this problem doesn't occur at all on my Samsung Galaxy S2. It only occurs on the Samsung Galaxy S5...

*CameraBridgeViewBase: OpenCV class which is used to capture (video)frames from the camera, show it and implements a 'onFrameListener' function.*

```
Parameters = 

phase-af-values
focallength-value-denominator=100
brightness-step=1
zoom=0
redeye-reduction-values=enable,disable
exif_iso=0
max-num-detected-faces-hw=10
scene-detect-values=off,on
qc-camera-features=542
face-detection-values=off,on
dynamic-range-control-values=
whitebalance=auto
max-sharpness=36
focallength-value-numerator=480
preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p
jpeg-thumbnail-quality=85
preview-format=yuv420sp
face-detection=off
auto-exposure-values=matrix,center,spot
iso=auto
fast-fps-mode=0
mce-values=enable,disable
flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,torch
preview-frame-rate=30
jpeg-thumbnail-width=512
video-size=1920x1080
scene-mode-values=auto,hdr
redeye-reduction=disable
preview-fps-range-values=(10000,30000)
histogram=disable
face-recognition=off
camera-mode=0
preview-size-values=1920x1080,1440x1080,1280x720,1056x864,960x720,800x480,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144
maxaperture-value-denominator=100
saturation-step=1
touch-af-aec=touch-off
smart-screen-exposure-values=vision-ae-normal,vision-ac-backlight
preview-fps-range=10000,30000
auto-whitebalance-lock=false
min-exposure-compensation=-4
llv_mode=0
antibanding=auto
max-num-focus-areas=1
face-recognition-values=off,on
vertical-view-angle=38
video-stabilization-supported=false
sce-factor-step=10
maxaperture-value-numerator=228
qc-max-num-requested-faces=10
min-saturation=0
max-saturation=10
contrast-step=1
raw-size=5328x3000
max-brightness=6
supported-live-snapshot-sizes=5312x2988,4128x2322,4000x3000,3264x2448,3264x1836,3200x2400,2592x1944,2048x1536,2048x1152,1920x1080,1600x1200,1440x1080,1280x768,1280x720,1024x768,800x600,800x480,800x450,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144
max-contrast=10
min-sce-factor=-100
picture-format-values=jpeg,bayer-qcom-10gbrg,bayer-qcom-10grbg,bayer-qcom-10rggb,bayer-qcom-10bggr,bayer-mipi-10gbrg,bayer-mipi-10grbg,bayer-mipi-10rggb,bayer-mipi-10bggr,yuv422sp
video-hfr=off
supported-shot-modes=normal-shot,panorama-burst
exposure-compensation-step=0.5
scene-detect=off
fnumber-value-numerator=220
picture-size=1920x1080
saturation=5
whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight
picture-format=jpeg
zsl=off
lensshade-values=enable,disable
selectable-zone-af=auto
video-hfr-values=60,90,150
iso-values=auto,ISO_HJR,100,200,400,800,1600
selectable-zone-af-values=
lensshade=enable
preferred-preview-size-for-video=1920x1080
anti-shake=0
min-sharpness=0
intelligent-mode=0
mce=enable
hfr-size-values=2664x1500,1328x748,824x496
snapshot-picture-flip=off
zoom-supported=true
metering=center
denoise-values=denoise-off,denoise-on
zsl-values=off,on
sharpness=36
phase-af=off
contrast=5
scene-mode=auto
jpeg-quality=96
dynamic-range-control=off
histogram-values=enable,disable
exif_exptime=0
metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0)
min-contrast=0
video-size-values=1920x1080,1440x1080,1280x720,800x450,800x480,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144
skinToneEnhancement=0
rt-hdr=off
preview-size=1920x1080
focal-length=4.80
ae-bracket-hdr-values=Off,AE-Bracket
denoise=denoise-on
video-flip=off
max-sce-factor=100
preview-frame-rate-values=15,24,30
max-num-metering-areas=10
preview-flip=off
focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,continuous-video,continuous-picture
vtmode=0
jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=512x288,480x288,256x154,432x288,512x384,352x288,320x240,176x144,0x0
zoom-ratios=100,104,109,114,119,125,129,134,139,144,150,154,159,164,169,175,179,184,189,194,200,204,209,214,219,225,229,234,239,244,250,254,259,264,269,275,279,284,289,294,300,304,309,314,319,325,329,334,339,344,350,354,359,364,369,375,379,384,389,394,400,404,409,414
dis-values=enable,disable
dual_mode=0
picture-size-values=5312x2988,3984x2988,3264x2448,3264x1836,2560x1920,2048x1152,1920x1080,1280x960,1280x720,800x480,640x480
touch-af-aec-values=touch-off,touch-on
smart-screen-exposure=0
luma-adaptation=3
min-brightness=0
horizontal-view-angle=62
firmware-mode=none
imageuniqueid-value=F16QLHF01GB
```

Comment: Added update to post above!

Comment: Jelmer, I have seen similar behavior on my Galaxy S5 (ignoring the iso setting) but only on front camera. The back camera seems to support setting of iso perfectly fine. Just my 2 cents.. Edit: by the way, I performed my tests on Galaxy S5 running Lollipop.